# Query working and non working hours average/Percentile utilisation of servers from influxdb over a month

Tags: influxdb, grafana, influxdb-python

I am using influxdb to store my production servers CPU/MEMORY utilisation.
Recently my customer asked whether it is possible to query out working hours and non working hours average utilisation of all the servers over a period of time or monthly. For ex the if the working hours is 6am - 6pm and non working hours is 6pm - 6am.
Is it possible to query the average utilisation of the servers over a month or certain week or days.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with InfluxDB alone, but should be possible with Kapacitor. You need to write TICKScript to filter and tag datapoints as working and non-working hours.

Here is the article that explains how to do exactly that: https://dzone.com/articles/enriching-your-data-with-kapacitor-influxdata